# My website is not working after upgrading Dotnetnuke to V7

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

I have this website, http://www.fagakademiet.no.

The site has a custom skin developed by a developer that already left the company.

We upgraded our DNN to V7 and now the Modules, Users Pages, Edit Page toolbar on top is not working.

I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'" error from dnn.jquery.js

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to the problem itself but
maybe you can try and switch back to the ribbon style toolbar instead in order to have the menu actions back.

You can find this under Host Settings -> Other settings -> Control Panel

Comment: It is working. tks. Off course, we still have the problem. It seems there's a conflict with different versions of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot to go on but here are some things to look at:
1.) You can't use the latest version of jQuery, 1.9. Use 1.8 or 1.7.2.
2.) Take a look at this thread. There are some issues with going into edit mode. Changing to the ribbon control panel is one possible, but not a particularly good one. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/190/threadid/469106/scope/posts.aspx